# Redirecting my old urls through .htaccess isn't working

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, syntax

I'm trying to alter my htaccess file to redirect, but it's not working and I'm not sure why. The old urls are now giving 404s if that's important.

```
Old structure: https://www.example.com/category/tag/id/slug
New structure: https://www.example.com/article/slug
```

I want to capture the slug and put it in the new structure. My htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/.*/.*/.*/(.*)$ /article/%1 [R=301,NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

I was thinking I had the last RewriteRule correct there, but perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: I saw an error in using %1 instead of $1, but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Correct syntax was:

```
RewriteRule ^.*/.*/.*/(.*) /article/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```